# My font is ignored in beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex

I use Xetex for customize my font.

I installed my font in my linux system.

The command `fc-list | grep -i Share-TechMono` returns `/usr/local/share/fonts/Share-TechMono.ttf: Share\-TechMono:style=Regular`

And this is my tex file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{wolverine}

\usepackage{textpos}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\setmainfont{Share-TechMono}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=black}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{TEST}
        \textbf{test!}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And the PDF is created but with the default font not the mine. Xetex does nt return an error.

Comment: Did you try (as I don't know the internals of beamer) `\AtBeginDocument{\setmainfont{Share-TechMono}}`?

Comment: Welcome! Add `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`. Otherwise, Beamer will override any custom font settings.

Comment: I use this command `\documentclass[Share-TechMono,professionalsfont]{beamer}` and I don't have error but the font don't change!

Comment: @sushi have you tried both the suggestions from the two comments above?